# Making a logarithmic scaled color plot including negative values

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm, axes, colorbar

I have a surface density map in matplotlib for which I want the scale of the colorbar to be logarithmic.

Ideally using the `LogNorm` function should do the trick, but there are negative and null values, which gives an error when the values are turned logarithmic.
Is there function/method that I can use to include the areas with negative and null values in this respect?

Comment: What do you want to happen to the negative and null values?  How do you want them to be incorporated into the log scaling?

Comment: And you can use masked arrays to exclude the null and negative values.

Comment: remember that `log(0) == -inf` and `log(-|x|) == nan`

Comment: @BrenBarn I don't want the values to be logged. Only the scale of the axis to be logarithmic, so the variation of the values can be seen much clearly.

Comment: @firefly: The values have to be logged at some point to create a logarithmic scale.  If you just want to display their relative differences, you could try scalinng them all up by adding a constant to all of them to make the smallest one bigger than zero.

Comment: The master branch of matplotlib on GitHub seems to include a new [`SymLogNorm`](http://matplotlib.org/dev/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm). From what I understand from your question, this might suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Use symmetric logarithmic normalization or the `SymLogNorm` to plot data with both positive and negative values. Look at this documentation: [Colormap Normalization](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html).